# How to pass array as a value of input while returning it from return response controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

In controller

$array = [{"Id": 1,
"Contract_ID": 2,
"Customer_Id": 3,
"Product_Id": "4",
"Product_Name": "KONICA MINOLTA 226i (RADF)",
"Product_Serial_key": "01"},{
"Id": 2,
"Contract_ID": 2,
"Customer_Id": 3,
"Product_Id": "5",
"Product_Name": "KYOCERA ECOSYS M2040DN",
"Product_Serial_key": "02"}];

I return the above array to the blade file.

`return view('blade_file_name',compact('array');`

I want to store this array as the value in an input tag.

`<input class="form-control" id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ $array }}">`

now i need to take this value as array using jquery $("#id").val();

but it's throwing an error saying string object invalid.

Comment: your `$array = [id:1,name:'John',location:'ohio',age:24'];` is not a valid PHP-Array nor valid JSON it also is not an string, is this an pasting mistake or maybe even your error?!

Comment: updated with valid array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
<input class="form-control" id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ json_encode($array) }}">
```

Then in Javascript use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
const id = $("#id").val(),
      json = JSON.parse(id);
```